# In R, how to read a special csv with some rows skipped the first value?

Tags: r, data-cleaning, read.csv

The data in Excel is like:
[image]

You can see the first column `Date` has some value missing, but by default they are just following the first value.

How I can read this kind of csv file into R? Should I do a script to replace these missing values then read them or there's some options in `read.csv()` to deal with this? I checked the official manual but couldn't find one.

To be more clear, the target is to automatically add the missing date directly into the csv files:

[image]

Comment: Could you read the file with readr::read_csv and then use zoo::na.locf to fill the missing values?

Comment: If the CSV file has been converted from Excel it should contain empty strings `""` for missing values; so `read.csv` should work just fine; or better still, use `readxl::read_excel` to read the Excel file directly. Then replace empty strings with `NA`'s, and use `zoo::na.locf` to fill with most recent values, as @Taran suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. But what I want to is to replace the empty string directly with the date in that segment. I didn't transform into excel, this is just for better visualize. I've copied another one.

Comment: Taran is correct, thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated**

you can use the *na.strings* parameter to replace the empty dates ("") with missing values (NA),

```
data = read.csv(your_file, header = TRUE, na.strings = c(""))
```

then,

```
data$Date = as.Date(data$Date)
data$Date = zoo::na.locf(data$Date)
```

to fill the missing values.

However, credit to @Taran, who commented your initial question, as I wasn't aware of the *zoo::na.locf* function.

Comment: Thanks so much! But I want to replace the na with the date values above, not empty string

Comment: Thanks for all! I didn't know that function too.